# 2d top down game you need to create random objects out of the player's field of view after they leave the field of view to delete

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

[image]Good afternoon, I can't implement random creation of objects outside the player's visibility zone so that after they exit they are deleted as an example of a cloud in the screenshot, thank you all in advance.

I have an idea that this problem can be implemented through the creation of "2 rectangles around the aircraft (player) far and near in the near we will have a spawn and in case an object hits the far object it will disappear, but how to implement it using scripts I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you can spawn objects in range upper corners by X axis and with constant offset(or configurable for every spawned object) by Y axis. To destroy spawned objects you can create some point in lower corners of  the camera view and when spawned object position by Y axis will be lower than this point Y - you will destroy object.
Or you can create some filtering object with `Collider2D` which width will be as width of the camera view and destroy object when will be triggered `OnCollisionExit2D`. Of course you should add collider to you spawned objects.
Several ideas which arose in the head.
Sorry, if my explanation is bad.